# warning illegal string offset while fetching result from database

Tags: php

I am using the following code to find the data from `database`

```
echo $query = "select * from `oc_order` where `store_url`='' ORDER BY `order_id` DESC LIMIT 5";
$mysqlq = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$mysqlw = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlq);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mysqlw);
foreach($mysqlw as $mysqlw)
{
    echo $mysqlw['telephone'];
}
?>
```

I am getting the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [order_id] => 73
    [1] => 0
    [invoice_no] => 0
    [2] => 
    [invoice_prefix] => 
    [3] => 0
    [store_id] => 0
    [4] => 
    [store_name] => 
    [5] => 
    [store_url] => 
    [6] => 9
    [customer_id] => 9
    [7] => 1
    [customer_group_id] => 1
    [8] => T****
    [firstname] => ****
    [9] => 
    [lastname] => 
    [10] => ********
    [email] => *******
    [11] => *****
    [telephone] => *****
    [12] => 
    [fax] => 
    [13] => 364ce6e2003bb1404f34
    [custom_field] => 364ce6e2003bb1404f34
    [14] => 
    [payment_firstname] => 
    [15] => 
    [payment_lastname] => 
    [16] => 
    [payment_company] => 
    [17] => 
    [payment_address_1] => 
    [18] => 
    [payment_address_2] => 
    [19] => 
    [payment_city] => 
    [20] => 
    [payment_postcode] => 
    [21] => 
    [payment_country] => 
    [22] => 0
    [payment_country_id] => 0
    [23] => 
    [payment_zone] => 
    [24] => 0
    [payment_zone_id] => 0
    [25] => 
    [payment_address_format] => 
    [26] => 
    [payment_custom_field] => 
    [27] => 
    [payment_method] => 
    [28] => 
    [payment_code] => 
    [29] => 
    [shipping_firstname] => 
    [30] => 
    [shipping_lastname] => 
    [31] => 
    [shipping_company] => 
    [32] => 
    [shipping_address_1] => 
    [33] => 
    [shipping_address_2] => 
    [34] => 
    [shipping_city] => 
    [35] => 
    [shipping_postcode] => 
    [36] => 
    [shipping_country] => 
    [37] => 0
    [shipping_country_id] => 0
    [38] => 
    [shipping_zone] => 
    [39] => 0
    [shipping_zone_id] => 0
    [40] => 
    [shipping_address_format] => 
    [41] => 
    [shipping_custom_field] => 
    [42] => 
    [shipping_method] => 
    [43] => 
    [shipping_code] => 
    [44] => 1,19
    [comment] => 1,19
    [45] => 100.0000
    [total] => 100.0000
    [46] => 0
    [order_status_id] => 0
    [47] => 0
    [affiliate_id] => 0
    [48] => 0.0000
    [commission] => 0.0000
    [49] => 0
    [marketing_id] => 0
    [50] => 
    [tracking] => 
    [51] => 0
    [language_id] => 0
    [52] => 0
    [currency_id] => 0
    [53] => INR
    [currency_code] => INR
    [54] => 1.00000000
    [currency_value] => 1.00000000
    [55] => 
    [ip] => 
    [56] => 
    [forwarded_ip] => 
    [57] => 
    [user_agent] => 
    [58] => 
    [accept_language] => 
    [59] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [60] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [date_modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)
```

but when i am trying to print the value of `echo $mysqlw['telephone'];` it is throwing warning `Warning: Illegal string offset 'telephone' in`

What mistake I am making in this code ?

Comment: `foreach($mysqlw as $mysqlw)` use a different variable. maybe `$mysqlw_single`

Comment: `$mysqlw = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlq);` is returning a single row into `$mysqlw`, and you're also redefining `$mysqlw` on each foreach loop. You want to iterate through `$mysqlq` to get the telephone number on each row.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do a foreach on the array that you've displayed in your post. That means you're cycling through each item in the array. By trying to access `$mysqlw['telephone']` you're expecting the item in the array to be *another* array containing the key 'telephone'.

I believe you're intending to do this:

```
while ($mysqlw = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlq) {
   echo $mysqlw['telephone'];
}
```

But also, you really should read up on how to do MySQL in a more modern style. Using things like mysqli_query in the manner you've used it here can open you up to injection attacks when you start having user input involved in the query.

Comment: mysqli is fairly modern, and it's fairly secure when using prepared statements and parameter binding. It's not an issue in this case because the OP isn't using any variables in their query.

Comment: @aynber yes, true; I just encourage people to get used to using prepared statements as much as possible to discourage bad habits sneaking in later.

Answer (score 1):

Note your foreach statement has same variable name on both sides of 'as'

```
foreach($mysqlw as $mysqlw)
```

If you want to loop and access each value of an array do this instead:

```
foreach($mysqlw as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: I think this is actually the right answer. I was thinking of the old school MS SQL syntax in my answer, I think!